# Do spell effects that trigger when you are hit still trigger if they do not penetrate your active Arcane Ward?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

I'm specifically wondering about the spells *Armor of Agathys*, *Fire Shield*, and *Shield*, but a general answer would be helpful.  For example, if a level 9 Abjuration Wizard/level 2 Warlock multiclass with an Arcane Ward with 20 hit points active, *Fire Shield* cast at 4th level, and *Armor of Agathys* cast at 5th level is hit by a melee attack that deals 15 damage, would the attacker take 25 points of cold damage from *Armor of Agathys* and 2d8 points of fire damage from *Fire Shield*, even though the attack did damage to your Arcane Ward, and not you?

Could you cast *Shield* in response to the attack in the example above to try and make it miss, or would that not work because *Shield* must be cast as a reaction to you being hit by an attack and the attack hit the Arcane Ward, instead of you?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### You are still *hit* by the attack so yes, spell effects the trigger on a hit would still trigger.

From page 194 of the PHB:

> #### Making An Attack
>
> Whether you're striking with a melee weapon, firing a weapon at range, or making an attack roll as part of a spell, an attack has a simple structure.
>
> [...]
>
> **3. Resolve the attack.** You make an attack roll. **On a hit,** you roll damage...

And Arcane Ward states:

> **Whenever you take damage,** the ward takes the damage instead. If this damage reduces the ward to 0 hit points, you take any remaining damage.

Damage is rolled *after* the attack hits and the attack roll and the *hit* are made against you, not the Arcane Ward. Nowhere in Arcane Ward's description does it modifier you being *hit* with an attack, it only modifies the damage you take *after* the hit.

Therefore, spells such as Armor of Agathys, Fire Shield, and Shield would still trigger.